# JQ - how to convert CSV with headers to JSON array with nested dictionaries

Tags: jq

I got the following CSV sample

```
key1,key2,key3,key4,key5
val1,val2,val3,val4,val5
```

Looking for tips how to convert the above structure into the following JSON structure

```
[
{
"event": "bleep",
"sourcetype": "rats",
"fields":  {
"key1":"val1",
"key2":"val2",
"key3":"val3",
"key4":"val4",
"key5":"val5"
 }
},
{
"event": "bleep",
"sourcetype": "rats",
"fields":  {
"key1":"val1",
"key2":"val2",
"key3":"val3",
"key4":"val4",
"key5":"val5"
 }
}
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-R` to read the input as raw text

```sh
jq -R '
  (. / ",") as $keys
  | [ inputs / "," | [$keys, .]
    | reduce transpose[] as $i (
        {event: "bleep", sourcetype: "rats"}; .fields[$i[0]] = $i[1])
      ]
' input.csv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZoAb12V6Fi)

Answer (score 0):

[Alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) lib can load the data file from server, parse it and put the result to array of JSON objects.

So, this is some example for you:

```
<script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
<script>
        alasql('SELECT * FROM CSV("FileName.csv",{headers:true})',[],function(res){
        var dataResult = {items:res};
        });
</script>
```